# ajax load gif not removing on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i currently have a table that loads a bunch of results via an ajax request you can see the code below. however when i try to add a loading gif i am only seeing the loading gif on the page it doesn't remove itself after the ajax request was suscessfull

i can see the page fire the ajax request and it return the data

i am chasing the loading bar to show while the ajax is processing then hide when its loaded

this is the html code

```
<div class='content'>
    <div class='panel panel-flat' id='records_loading'>
        <table class='table table-togglable table-hover table-striped' data-limit-navigation='5' data-page-size='20'>
            <thead class='bg-teal'>
                <tr>
                    <th data-toggle='true' data-type='numeric'>SMS ID</th>
                    <th data-hide='phone'>Time Stamp</th>
                    <th data-hide='phone,tablet'>Mobile Number</th>
                    <th data-hide='phone,tablet'>Message</th>
                    <th data-hide='phone,tablet'>Message Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody  id='records_table'>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<ul class='pagination pagination-separated hide-if-no-paging'></ul>
</div>
```

this is the ajax code

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {  
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getjson.php?search='+str, 
        type: 'POST',    
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend:function(response)
       {
        $('#records_loading').html('<img src="assets/content/login.gif">');
       },
        success: function (response) 
        {
          var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             trHTML += 
                '<tr><td>' + value.ID + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Timestamp + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Number + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Message + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Status + 
                '</td></tr>';     
          });
            $('#records_table').html(trHTML);
            $('.table-togglable').trigger('footable_redraw');
        }
    }); 
}
showResult('');
</script>
```

Comment: _"it doesn't remove itself"_ it won't remove itself, just like you had to add it in, you have to do the removing

Comment: after var trHTML = ''; put  $('#records_table').html('');

Comment: @jeff, why would they need to do that? `$('#records_table').html(trHTML);` will wipe out any text/html currently in the element and replace it with whatever `trHTML` holds

Comment: @PatrickEvans I know the OP code should work but maybe jQuery is doing something strange so wiping out the contents first might help the situation.

Comment: what im actually chasing is the div to have a loading bar inside of it until the ajax has completed then it displays the data

Answer (score 1):

```
    success: function (response) 
    {
       $('#records_loading').html('<table class='table table-togglable table-hover table-striped' data-limit-navigation='5' data-page-size='20'><thead class='bg-teal'>');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this instead for better user experience and display:

html: //add the following code anywhere in your html code

```
<img src="assets/content/login.gif" id="loader" style="display:none;position:fixed;z-index:9999;top:50%;left:50%;">
```

javascript:

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {  
    $("#loader").fadeIn();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/getjson.php?search='+str, 
    type: 'POST',    
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) 
    {
      var trHTML = '';
      $.each(response, function (key,value) {
         trHTML += 
        '<tr><td>' + value.ID + 
        '</td><td>' + value.Timestamp + 
        '</td><td>' + value.Number + 
        '</td><td>' + value.Message + 
        '</td><td>' + value.Status + 
        '</td></tr>';     
      });
        $('#records_table').html(trHTML);
        $('.table-togglable').trigger('footable_redraw');
    }
    });   
    $("#loader").fadeOut();
}
showResult('');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Only one change..**

Use

```
$('#records_table').html('<img src="assets/content/login.gif">');
```

Instead of

```
$('#records_loading').html('<img src="assets/content/login.gif">');
```

Final Code:

```
<script>
function showResult(str) {  
    $.ajax({
        url: '/getjson.php?search='+str, 
        type: 'POST',    
        dataType:'json',
        beforeSend:function(response)
       {
        $('#records_table').html('<img src="assets/content/login.gif">');
        $('#records_loading thead.bg-teal').hide();
       },
        success: function (response) 
        {
          var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             trHTML += 
                '<tr><td>' + value.ID + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Timestamp + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Number + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Message + 
                '</td><td>' + value.Status + 
                '</td></tr>';     
          });
            $('#records_loading thead.bg-teal').show();
            $('#records_table').html(trHTML);
            $('.table-togglable').trigger('footable_redraw');
        }
    }); 
}
showResult('');
</script>
```

Comment: this works however it still shows the table header if possible i want it to hide the table header till its loaded

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any code to remove the `loading.gif` on success.
Like to show the gif you wrote a snippet in `beforeSend` function, you can write a code to remove the gif on success. The following snippet will empty the `record_loading` container

```
$('#records_loading').empty();
```